# How to guarantee a bean is instantiated only once by Spring

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know how to tell Spring load a bean which I've defined in a context just once? Is this possible? How is this called and what do I need to do?

I'd basically like to make sure the class is never re-instantiated and that the same instance is re-used.

Comment: Please show your context. A combination of `@Bean`, `<bean>` or `scope` and `@Scope` is enough.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Thanks for the useful link, yet again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All beans in spring are [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) by [default](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html) so they will be instantiated just once. So you have this out of the box and need just to register bean in context by `xml` or `Annotations`.

Comment: This was my impression, but I wasn't sure where to check it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Silviu, I am well aware, thanks. However, it takes 10 minutes from post to accept.

Answer (score 4):

Single instance is the default behavior. Unless you're loading multiple contexts, you should have only one instance.

Comment: So, if I have several contexts, what would be the behavior? Do I need to explicitly specify `scope="singleton"`?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Singleton is the default.

Comment: One of the web apps I was working with, had a default context loaded by spring. In addition, there was BeansUtility class which allowed developers to get beans using static method without injecting them into objects. That utility was creating a duplicate context with duplicate set of beans. If you're loading multiple context which define the same beans, I'm not sure if there's a way to ensure a single instance as those context cannot see each other.

Comment: God, no! I wouldn't be doing something like that. Thanks for clearing it out.

Answer (score 3):

bean register in xml congiguration file we can specify the scope of the bean
but the defult scope of the bean is singletone.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid to load the applicationContext.xml multiple times.